# Counting rows iterativly that have a column correlation?

Tags: mysql, subquery, iteration, conditional-statements

Given the table containing the columns: custID, startDate, endDate, etc.

How would one go about counting the highest number of rows that a customer generated existing within the same time period.

My thinking is that if you do a recursive JOIN and eliminate the rows that are identical you could compare A.startDate with B start and end dates.

I simply don't understand how to do this iterative process to find the highest number possible.

What I have right now look like this but it doesn't seem to work as intended.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.custID, COUNT(A.custID) AS Concurrently
FROM T_Loan A JOIN T_Loan B
WHERE A.custID = B.custID AND NOT (A.endDate = B.endDate AND A.loanDate = B.startDate) AND A.startDate<= B.endDate AND A.startDate>= B.startDate
GROUP BY custID
HAVING Concurrently > 0;
```

Any advice or suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: SELECT B.custID, B.endDate AS 'end', B.startDate AS 'start', COUNT(*)
FROM T_Loan A JOIN T_Loan B
WHERE A.custID = B.custID
GROUP BY B.endDate, B.startDate;

Currently the count just tells me the number of entries from a custID, but I'm thinking if I place a sub-query inside the count joining that row with all possible rows from the corresponding customer and try to apply the filter there i might get something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the comparison of `loanDate` to `startDate` in the query, and checking for a date range overlap seems to be referencing a wrong column.

Assuming that `(custid,startdate,enddate)` is a unique identifier for a row in `T_Loan`...  (ideally, we'd have a single column as a unique identifier for example, an `id` column as a surrogate primary key) and assuming that we're only interested in rows where all three of the columns are non-NULL...

Those are some big assumptions, but all we have to go on is the information provided in the question.

As a start, I'd figure out how to get a count of the number of rows in `T_Loan` that are for the same `custid` and are concurrent (that is, there's any amount of overlap in the start/end date ranges.)

For simplicity, I'd go ahead and include the current row in that count, so a row with no other concurrent rows would be reported with a count of 1 (the row itself). Here's how I'd do that:

```
SELECT a.custid
     , a.startdate
     , a.enddate
     , COUNT(b.custid)  AS cnt_concurrent
  FROM T_Loan a
  JOIN T_Loan b
    ON b.custid     = a.custid
   AND b.enddate   >= a.startdate
   AND b.startdate <= a.enddate
 GROUP
    BY a.custid
     , a.startdate
     , a.enddate
```

That gives us, for each row in `T_Loan` a count of the number of rows in `T_Loan` that are for the same `custid` and there's some overlap in the date range with the current row.

We can use the resultset returned by that query as a rowsource in another query.

For example, to get the maximum number of concurrent rows for each `custid`, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT c.custid
     , MAX(c.cnt_concurrent) AS max_cnt_concurrent
  FROM (
         SELECT a.custid
              , a.startdate
              , a.enddate
              , COUNT(b.custid)  AS cnt_concurrent
           FROM T_Loan a
           JOIN T_Loan b
             ON b.custid     = a.custid
            AND b.enddate   >= a.startdate
            AND b.startdate <= a.enddate
          GROUP
             BY a.custid
              , a.startdate
              , a.enddate
       ) c
 GROUP BY c.custid
```

This is going to include `custid` that have only one row in `T_Loan`, as well as `custid` where there are multiple rows, but no overlap in the date ranges. If we want to eliminate those rows (with a maximum concurrent count equal to 1), we can add a `HAVING` clause...

```
HAVING MAX(c.cnt_concurrent) > 1
```

---

This query is an example of just one approach; there are other approaches we can use.